# sql equivalent of R query

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I have two data sets author_data and paper_author

author_data:

```
author_id       author_name          author_affiliation
 25         William H. Nailon                                                                    
 37         P. B. Littlewood        Cavendish Laboratory|Cambridge University
 44         A. Kuroiwa               Department of Molecular Biology
```

paper_author:

```
paper_id     author_id      author_name      author_affiliation
  1          521630         Ayman Kaheel     Cairo Microsoft Innovation Lab
  1          972575       Mahmoud Refaat     Cairo Microsoft Innovation Lab
```

I have run the following query in R

```
author_data[which(author_data$author_id %in% paper_author$author_id &
                  author_data$author_name %in% paper_author$author_name & 
                  author_data$author_affiliation %in% paper_author$author_affiliation), ]
```

That is, I want to find out the matches between author_data and paper_author for which the three columns `author_id`, `author_name` and `author_affiliation` match.

I have written a query to get this result in sql but I am not getting it right.The query which I have tried is

```
statement <- "select
              author_data.author_id,
              author_data.author_name,
              author_data.author_affiliation
        FROM author_data
        INNER JOIN paper_author
          ON author_data.author_id = paper_author.author_id
            AND author_data.author_name = paper_author.author_name
            AND author_data.author_affiliation = paper_author.author_affiliation"
```

through this query I am getting more rows than the rows in author_data and the query should fetch data which first of all would be subset of author_data. I am not able to figure out what is wrong as I am naive at sql.

What is wrong with this query?

Thanks

Comment: __You__ should tell us what is wrong with that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `which` in R and `join` in SQL. While `which` will effectively subset given data frame, `join` will return all rows where `join` condition is met. I am almost sure, that in your case you have multiple occurences of combination `author_id, author_name, author_affiliation` in `paper_author`. As a result, rows in `author_data` are multiplied by rows in `paper_author`.

Your query was almost correct, you need to add `distinct` or `group by` or use `exists`:

Distinct:

```
select
   distinct
   author_data.author_id,
   author_data.author_name,
   author_data.author_affiliation
from
   author_data
   INNER JOIN paper_author
          ON author_data.author_id = paper_author.author_id
            AND author_data.author_name = paper_author.author_name
            AND author_data.author_affiliation = paper_author.author_affiliation
```

Group by:

```
select
   author_data.author_id,
   author_data.author_name,
   author_data.author_affiliation
from
   author_data
   INNER JOIN paper_author
          ON author_data.author_id = paper_author.author_id
            AND author_data.author_name = paper_author.author_name
            AND author_data.author_affiliation = paper_author.author_affiliation
group by
   author_data.author_id,
   author_data.author_name,
   author_data.author_affiliation
```

You can also use `exists`:

```
select
   author_data.author_id,
   author_data.author_name,
   author_data.author_affiliation
from
   author_data
where
   exists (select 1 from paper_author where
       author_data.author_id = paper_author.author_id
       AND author_data.author_name = paper_author.author_name
       AND author_data.author_affiliation = paper_author.author_affiliation
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT author_data.author_id,author_data.author_name,author_data.author_affiliation
FROM author_data, paper_author
WHERE author_data.author_id = paper_author.author_id 
AND author_data.author_name=paper_author.author_name 
AND author_data.author_affiliation=paper_author.author_affiliation
```